# Xpath Is there a less verbose way to filter with multiple 'contain' conditions?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

```
and (contains(BusinessType,'Restaurant') or contains(BusinessType,'Pub') or contains(BusinessType,'Takeaway') <snip...>)
```

The above works as expected returning cases containing the specified words, but is there a less verbose/more efficient code?

Something like this, but actually works?

```
and (contains(BusinessType,'Restaurant|Pub|Takeaway'))
```

Comment: Possibly reversing the  parameters of the `contains()` function could work for you (as mentioned below, it's not quite clear what the goal here is). In any case, in XSLT 2.0 you have better options (as also shown below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`matches()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-3/#func-matches) takes a regex and will do what you want:

```
matches(BusinessType,'Restaurant|Pub|Takeaway')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you truly want ***substring containment** testing against a set of possible substrings* (i.e. `BusinessType` should match not only `'Restaurant'` but also `'Fine Dining Restaurant'` and `'Non-Restaurants'`), then see Mads' answer (+1).

If you actually want ***string equality** testing against a set of possible values*, update the regex as follows,

```
matches(BusinessType, '^(Restaurant|Pub|Takeaway)$')
```

or use this cleaner form instead:

```
BusinessType = ('Restaurant', 'Pub', 'Takeaway')
```